# c3.js cannot load lines value

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I post some code here.I don't know why the value of lines in old_chart can't update. 
I have been searched all I can do.So I wish U guys can help me to figure out this.
Thanks a lot!!

```
        <script>
    old_chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
     data: {
    columns: []
    },
     grid: {
    x: {
    show: true
    },
     y: {
    show: true,
     lines: []
    }
    }
    });

   $.ajax({type:"GET",
            url:"threshold",
            success: function(result){
              threshold_in_server = JSON.parse(result);
              input_threshold(threshold_in_server);

            }
    });

input_threshold = function(threshold_in_server){

      old_chart.load({
        y: {
              lines: [{value:threshold_in_server[0] },
                      {value:threshold_in_server[1] }]
            }
       });
    };
    </script>
<body>
<div id='chart' style='position:absolute;top:25px'></div>
<>/body
```

Comment: You get **result**, but you do nothing with it. How do you expect it to work?

Comment: I edit my code,used ajax to get values from server,put values into old_chart.load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update additional grid lines you should use **[.ygrids()](http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-ygrids)** api method, **not .load()**:

```
old_chart.ygrids([{value:threshold_in_server[0] },
                  {value:threshold_in_server[1] }])
```

Comment: thanks,it can run perfectly.I didn't know this function before.Could you tell me where can I learn more about `c3.js`.I think  examples on  [c3.js](http://c3js.org/) isn't enough for me.